# How to add a non-quoted delimiter at the end of a Clojure sequence

Tags: clojure

I have lines of data in a sequence of sequences and each sequence is different but follows the general pattern as follows:

`("44999" "186300" "194300" "0" "380600" "325" "57" "0")`

When I write the sequence of sequences out to a file using

```
(defn write-csv-file
  "Writes a csv file using a key and an s-o-s"
  [out-sos out-file]

  (if (= dbg 1)
    (println (first out-sos), "\n", out-file))

  (spit out-file "" :append false)
  (with-open [out-data (io/writer out-file)]
      (csv/write-csv out-data out-sos)))
.
.
.
(write-csv-file out-re "re_values.csv")
```

the data comes out like this

`44999,186300,194300,0,380600,325,57,0`

That is exactly the way I want it (unquoted), except, I'd like a unquoted ',' at the end of each sequence.

I've tried `(concat one-row (list \,))` and trying to add a ',' at the end of each sequence in a `(list` function, but I cannot get an unquoted ',' at the end of each sequence. How can I do this?

As a workaround, I can run files like this through sed to add the trailing comma, but I'd like to do it all in Clojure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you do not want to "add a comma" but add an empty field (which is then separated by a comma).  So, you should simply add an empty string to your line sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe concat an empty string to each sequence inside of out-sos. Concat is lazy, so shouldn't be expensive.

```
(with-open [out-data (io/writer out-file)]
  (csv/write-csv out-data (map #(concat % [""]) out-sos))))
```

Not sure what the csv library would do with an empty at the end though. Hopefully you would just get your empty element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :end-of-line setting to ",\n"

This is what the documentation says:

> :end-of-line
>
> A string containing the end-of-line character for writing CSV files.
>
> Default value: \n

This what I tried:

```
(csv/write-csv data :end-of-line ",\n")
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not originally see this. Can you give me a pointer to an example? I see :end-of-line in the documentation, but not how to use it.

Comment: I tried your solution, but cannot seem to get to work with the syntax I've listed above, specifically                          `(with-open [out-data (io/writer out-file)]
 (csv/write-csv out-data out-sos)))`

Comment: I don't see :end-of-line associated with clojure.data.csv. I do see it associated with clojure-csv. Does that make a difference?